# Free terminal based dictionary for Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, dictionary

I'm looking for a dictionary that can be used from the terminal. I'm expecting something like `dictionary <word-in-double-quotes>`. Should be installable from `apt` and should be free.

PS: OS - Kali Linux

Answer (score 1):

- [sdcv](https://github.com/Dushistov/sdcv) - console version of Stardict
- [dictd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dictd) daemon
- [aspell](http://aspell.net/) (may be already installed)
- [`grep /usr/share/dict/<dictionary file>`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245924/what-is-usr-share-dict-used-for)

My personal choice is `grep /usr/share/dict/<dictionary file>`, since there is nothing to install, and `grep` is based on regular expressions, including Perl regexes, for example this:

```
grep -P -i '^f.[a-p]k(it)?$' /usr/share/dict/words
```

Prints exactly what you would have predicted:

```
fack
feak
feck
fink
flak
folk
fulk
funk
```

**See also:**

- [Is there an offline command-line dictionary? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191125/is-there-an-offline-command-line-dictionary)
- [GNU `grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
- [perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: While the answer is not wrong, the site is **Recommendations**. As such, your answer is more valuable if you post your experience. Regardless, they all need more details as to their pros and cons.

Comment: @RohitGupta Thank you, updated the answer.